File mysteriously growing in size
I have an implementation of the Rijndael algorithm, where I create an array from a file, encrypt it, and write it to another file. The array never changes in size, and all of the values stay in 0-255 range the entire time. But the file I read from is ~1KB in size, and the resulting file is ~27KB in size. What causes this?
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
from time import time
from random import getrandbits

KEY = getrandbits(128)
FILE_TO_ENCRYPT = "testfile.txt"
ROUNDS = 9

Sbox = (
# Too long and doesnt matter
)

def bin_to_hex_arr(num):
    hexa = hex(num).replace("0x", "")
    hexa = [int(hexa[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(hexa), 2)]
    hexa = np.array(hexa)
    return hexa.reshape([4, 4]).astype(np.int8)

def tohex(val, nbits=8):
  return hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))

def substitute(byte):
    hexByte = tohex(byte).replace("0x", "")
    if len(hexByte) > 1:
        y = int(hexByte[0], 16)
        x = int(hexByte[1], 16)
    else:
        y = 0
        x = int(hexByte, 16)
    c = y * 16 + x
    return Sbox[c]

def main():
    file = np.fromfile(FILE_TO_ENCRYPT, dtype=np.uint8)
    print("Key:", hex(KEY))

    # Puts file into array of 4x4 boxes
    num_boxes = int(np.ceil(len(file) / 16))
    padding = np.zeros(
        16 - (len(file) % 16)
    )
    file = np.append(file, padding)
    file = file.reshape([num_boxes, 4, 4])

    # XORs with key
    key_4x4 = bin_to_hex_arr(KEY)
    print("Key:", key_4x4)
    for box in file:
        for x in range(4):
            for y in range(4):
                box[x][y] = int(box[x][y]) ^ int(key_4x4[x][y])

    for _ in range(ROUNDS):
        file = np.array([substitute(int(b)) for b in file.ravel()]).reshape([num_boxes, 4, 4])

    # saves file
    save = open(f"{FILE_TO_ENCRYPT}.encrypt", "wb")
    for val in file.ravel():
        save.write(bytes(val))
    save.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = time()
    main()
    e = time()
    print(f"{round(e - s, 2)}s")



I get an error, "tuple index out of range" from return Sbox[c]

you need to add the value of Sbox so we can run this.

BTW, you can use file.flat instead of file.ravel(), so it doesn't need to create a new array.

Sbox is a 256 long array of hex values, i just left it out beacause it took up a lot of space, the values themselves dont matter as long as they are 00-FF

So just set it to a random array, so the code works.

I fixed the problem. It was with the save file method at the bottom. I changed it to save.write(bytearray(file)) instead of for val in file.ravel(): save.write(bytes(val))

You should post that as an answer below.
